# maven compiler plugin not pass compiler J-Xbootclasspath/p args

Tags: java, maven, checker-framework

**-J-Xbootclasspath/p: is not passed by maven compiler plugin,how can I workaround it?**

System enviroment: jdk 1.8.0_265,windows 10.
maven file: I copied it from CheckerFramework example [pom.xml](https://github.com/typetools/checker-framework/blob/master/docs/examples/MavenExample/pom.xml).

```
<compilerArgs>
  <!-- using github.com/google/error-prone-javac is required when running on JDK 8 -->
  <arg>-J-Xbootclasspath/p:${errorProneJavac}</arg>
  <!-- -Awarns treats Checker Framework errors as warnings -->
  <!-- <arg>-Awarns</arg> -->
  <!--
    For the Subtyping Checker, annotations defined in module 'your-qual-artifact':
    <arg>-Aquals=myPackage.qual.MyFenum,myPackage.qual.MyCustomType</arg>
  -->
  <arg>-Alint</arg>
  <!-- If using JDK 11 remove the two arguments above and uncomment the one below. -->
  <!-- <arg>-J- -add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED</arg> -->
  <!-- -Awarns turns type-checking errors into warnings. -->
  <!-- <arg>-Awarns</arg> -->
</compilerArgs>
```

When I first run it by mvn clean compile,it fall with

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project MavenExample: Compilation failure

So I run mvn clean compile -X  then found that -J-Xbootclasspath/p:/path/to/javac.jar not included in the command line option.
Then I tred include "-J-Xbootclasspath/p" in and mannualy javac compile it and it successed.  But I need use it in maven,so I ask the question.

this is the  printed failed command line option

> [DEBUG]
> -d D:\workproject\TestCheck\target\classes
> -classpath D:\workproject\TestCheck\target\classes;C:\Users\张云.m2\repository\org\checkerframework\checker-qual\3.6.1\checker-qual-3.6.1.jar;C:\Users\张云.m2\repository\com\google\errorprone\javac\9+181-r4173-1\javac-9+181-r4173-1.jar;C:\Users\张云.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.1\commons-lang3-3.1.jar;C:\Users\张云.m2\repository\javax\servlet\servlet-api\2.4\servlet-api-2.4.jar;
> -sourcepath D:\workproject\TestCheck\src\main\java;D:\workproject\TestCheck\target\generated-sources\annotations; D:\workproject\TestCheck\src\main\java\Main.java
> -s D:\workproject\TestCheck\target\generated-sources\annotations
> -processor org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.NullnessChecker
> -processorpath C:\Users\张云.m2\repository\org\checkerframework\checker\3.6.1\checker-3.6.1.jar;
> -g -verbose -target 1.8 -source 1.8 -encoding UTF-8 -Alint

this is the complete log file [log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qIidGNaO8EdWptJp6G4zu_wU1pe3dJ-D/view?usp=sharing)

and [project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kb6ax-FYcNEc5Vp9OA7dq_k08DMgYghf/view?usp=sharing) file

Comment: Could you please provide a complete [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?  It should include a complete project, including the full `pom.xml` file you are using (not just a snippet of it), so that others can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @mernst As your request ,I upload the project file.It's just a hello world project and its pom.xml is a copy from the checker framework example pom.xml url.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for providing the project; that is very helpful.

When I ran `mvn -e -B clean install --debug`, the Checker Framework worked properly:  it issued an error about `return null` on line 10 of file `Main.java`:

```
[ERROR] /home/mernst/tmp/TestCheck/src/main/java/Main.java:[10,15] error: [return.type.incompatible] incompatible types in return.
  type of expression: null
  method return type: @Initialized @NonNull String
```

The full log is at https://pastebin.com/4kHe4WMz .

There are some suspicious differences between my output and the log that you provided.

My output, when running on the project you provided, contains:

```
  <compilerArgs>
    <arg>-J-Xbootclasspath/p:${com.google.errorprone:javac:jar}</arg>
    <arg>-Alint</arg>
  </compilerArgs>
```

By contrast, the log you pasted contains:

```
  <compilerArgs>
    <arg>-Alint</arg>
  </compilerArgs>
  <compilerArgument>-J-Xbootclasspath/p:/a/b</compilerArgument>
```

I don't have an explanation for the difference.  For example, I don't know where the `/a/b` path in your output came from, since that doesn't appear in the project you provided.  I suspect that you pasted a log from a different project, with a different `pom.xml`, than the project you provided.

Comment: sorry for the /a/b confuse,the /a/b thing is just a test which change path from unicode contained path  to unix like path for exclude the encode error possibility,when upload the log file I forgot change it back.this is the project file log https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qIidGNaO8EdWptJp6G4zu_wU1pe3dJ-D/view?usp=sharing

Comment: yes.the null check error is waht I expected.But I only got the maven compile exception .You pasted compilerArgs log is the same  as I updated log.But it is not work in my place.

Comment: for the username,when upload log,I changed the username to protect privicy.
just for clarity.

Comment: when I javac compile use the command line option from log file with -J-Xbootclasspath/p: I compiled with null check error as expected. so i guess is this happen because arg missing.but in your log file this arg is aslo not printed in command line option but you success. I have no idea what is wrong now.

Comment: I think that this question is resolved:  there is no problem.  You could open a new question in which you give the *actual* project, the *actual* command, and the *actual* log output, with no editing or elision.  If you want to protect your privacy, then create a new user account on your computer and do work from there.